# Does Bourbaki prove Minkowski inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Where, if anywhere, in Bourbaki's *Elements of Mathematics* is the Minkowski inequality proved (for $n$-tuples of real numbers, not for $L^p$-spaces).

Comment: $n$-tuple case is a special case of $L^p$ on the set $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ with discrete topology (locally compact topological space). The answer is almost surely, no(